# Twelve rebus puzzles

Tags: rebus

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[How many did I catch?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56493/how-many-did-i-catch-simplified-duplicate?noredirect=1&lq=1) Answer this after you have solved the 12 steps above.

Comment: Is the cursor under 11 intentional?

Comment: No the cursor is not intentional

Comment: You may as well delete this now you've posted the simpler version

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil This seems to be a valid first part of a two-part puzzle. I've now edited both puzzles to bring them more into line with that, so that neither needs to be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for posting this here, but the other location, as a duplicate, is blocked for new answers.

The number caught is:

> 25

The number missed is:

> also 25

The reason is that:

> each of the 12 rebus words has an even number of letters, and is a concatenation of the 2 letter US state abbreviations. There are 35 such bigrams, but 10 are duplicates, leaving 25 "caught" and 25 "missed".

Not quite sure of the principle by which some are chosen to be caught. There are other words which could easily be made from the missing ones:

> (e.g. FLAK, INKY, INKS, VAIN...).

Thanks for a fun enigma!

Comment: Great catch (no pun intended).  I had tried to follow the even number of letters point also but got nowhere.  Good job!

Comment: Great job. I was just about to answer my own question.

Comment: It was hard to come up with a good Rebus for some of the additional words like VAIN

Comment: No worries I think you struck a good balance :D

Answer (score 2):

I will throw out there what I have at this point.

My theory:

> I think that what has to be done is to find the character matches from one answer to the next and total them up and that is the answer

1. Is Palm + Pond - Ps

   > almond
2. Pemberton 1886 is:

   > coca-cola
   > almonds matched to coca-cola is 3
3. 

> Ohms
> Ohms matched to coca-cola is 1

4. I am quite certain that is a

   > Condor
   > Ohms matched to condor is 1
5. I think the idea with the flower is

   > Nectar
   > condor matched to nectar is 1
6. that is a bowl of

   > calamari
   > nectar matched to calamari is 2
7. I have an idea on this one but need more work...

> sord + seal - Ss = ordeal
>  calamari matched to ordeal is 3

8. that is a picture of a moon named

   > Ganymede
   > Ganymede matched to ordeal is 2
9. that is a

   > pail
   > Ganymede matched to pail is 1
10. I am going to say that is

    > goblets
    > goblets matched to pail is 1
11. lion from animated movie

    > working on the name...Scar according to others.
    > Scar matched to goblets is 0
12. Maori woman

    > I was just informed by my step mother that a Maori woman is called a wahine. 
    >  turns out that she knows because she has some ancestry in that direction...
    >  Wahine matched to Scar is 1

total so far is

> 16
>  You caught 16

Comment: the lion is Scar from lion king

Comment: I can see this is turning out to be tougher to establish commonality. Many of them you have are correct. Try Pail instead of bucket, Ohms in place of omegas, nectar instead of pollen. 7 could be the hardest one I guess

Comment: 7 is indeed near-impossible. You need to figure out the exact species of the birds, and then you need to know the [obsolete collective noun for them](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sord). After that it gets much easier :-)  (That's the only new part I got, so you get a comment instead of a partial answer)

Comment: You re right. So it is a name for flock of mallards

Comment: What do the "is matched to" bits mean??

Comment: @feelinferrety   My thinking right now is that the "match" has to do with the characters from the previous answer that are also in that answer.  For example almond matches three characters with coca-cola.  You would then just make a list of the "matches" and add them up to get his final "catches".  On the other hand I could be completely in the ditch with this approach.  I still have to figure out the answer for a couple of them.  Working on it.

Comment: And now it seems that the answers have been posted somewhere else...just as I was getting it figured out.

Comment: Yes, it seems OP decided to ditch this approach and go for one layer at a time. I would put your "theory" up top to clarify what you are talking about with the whole "match" thing.

Comment: @feelinferrety  I will move the theory to the top although it may be moot now

Answer (score 0):

are these..

> drinks ?

because as I understand...

> 1. oasis
>  2. coca-cola
>  3. Omega energy drink
>  4. Golden eagle energy drink
>  5.
>  6.
>  7.
>  8. Jupiter cocktail drink
>  9.
>  10.
>  11. False King cocktail
>  12.

Comment: I don't believe that's meant to be an eagle...