# How many did I catch?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, word-property

This is a simplified version of [the original puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56431/how-many-did-i-catch?noredirect=1&lq=1) since there was some difficulty with the pictures.

How many did I catch? How many did I leave out?

1. Almond
2. Coca cola
3. Ohms
4. Condor
5. Nectar
6. Calamari
7. Ordeal
8. Ganymede
9. Pail
10. Wine
11. Scar
12. Wahine

Looking for answer to the question how many were left out when you study all these words

> Hint: Commonality

Comment: What the heck is the question? Catch what?

Comment: Edited version still makes no sense.... how many WHAT were left out?

Comment: @Tvde1 I'm assuming it's a [tag:enigmatic-puzzle].

Comment: @feelinferrety Much as I would like the chance to use my [tag:riddle] dupehammer, I think it's valid to post these as two separate puzzles. It's a two-parter: first solve the rebuses to find the words, then find the pattern among the words. (Both need a little editing/retagging though, which I'll do in a second.)

Comment: I don't know, "catch" reminds me of ... rot13(... svfu naq v frr buz[f nyzba]q, f[pne c]nvy naq pnyn[znev ar]p[gne jnuvar]).

Comment: If you would like to update the puzzle, you can edit it rather than posting it anew.

Comment: Have posted what I think is the right answer in "Twelve rebus puzzles"

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> 3 missed(left out)  2 caught

or:

> 3 caught 4 missed(left out)

because:

> The first letters create a netting pattern since they're handles they're ignored. If you include the "o" it's 3 missed, 2 caught, if not it's 3 caught, 4 missed.  [image: Puzzle]